# Unique Constraint Violated: Eclipselink JPA SecuenceGenerator, Cascade Persist with Oracle

Tags: oracle, jpa, sequence, cascade, unique-constraint

I am getting the following eclipselink error:

I have an entity with a JPA SequenceGenerator, in unit, and user tests it works correctly if there are few users connected, but if there is a greater concurrency of users, the following error is randomly presented:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
ORA-00001: unique constraint violated Error Code: 1 Call: INSERT INTO LIST_DOCUMENT (COD_LIST_DOC, APPLY, COD_DOC, COD_REPO, NAME, ROUTE_REPO, SINI_SOL_SAI_SOLICIT, SINIESTRO_FEC_REP) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?)
```

In other projects I have seen solutions of similar cases using triggers, deactivation of cache, simple redeployments, or reading the sequence from BD with a sql statement, but I ask if anyone has any other idea, since by normal jpa operation this should not happen .

This is serious because it affects our acceptance tests.

This is the annotation of the id.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "COD_LIST_DOC")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "secListDoc")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "secListDoc", sequenceName = "SEC_LIS_DOCUMENTO", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
private BigDecimal codListDoc;
```

This is the .sql of the sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "INDEMNITY". "SEC_LIS_DOCUMENT" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 261 NOCACHE ORDER NOCYCLE;
```

This is the nextval of the sequence:
 
`select SEC_LIS_DOCUMENTO.nextval from dual;` It returns -> 261

In the table the inserted object id is 260.

Eclipselink version:
 
    
     org.eclipse.persistence 
     org.eclipse.persistence.jpa 
     2.6.4

I am using:

- Weblogic version 12.1.1.0.12
- jdk 1.7
- Oracle 11.2.0.3

As additional information it is a list that persists as cascade child from father

```
em.persist (obj); 

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "SiniestrolistaDocumentoSiniestroFk", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@PodamExclude
private List <Document List> SinStroFkesDocument list;
```

Comment: If the INSERT has a trigger which tries to insert a record (probably with the same ID) into a secondary table, that may be the problem (and you won't see the offending, "recursive" statement). Can you trace the process at the database level?

Answer (score 2):

A sequence will be unique (and not necessarily gapless), so I wouldn't blame it.

Perhaps you should first check MAX value of a column populated by that sequence, and then recreate the sequence using MAX+1 as sequence's MINVALUE.

Furthermore, check what unique constraint looks like. It doesn't have to be enforced on a single column and  maybe it is set to a different column than you think.

Comment: The CREATE SEQUENCE statement (obviously extracted from the data dictionary) shows the right MAX()+1 value. Except for that, good advice.